# How to calculate get cumulative values for a table, which is reset to '0' at the start of each month?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an interest column that calculates the interest per day and shows the result for a month on a cumulative basis. For example,

```
report_date     Interest
1/1/2021        10
2/1/2021        20
3/1/2021        30
.
.
.
1/2/2021        10
```

Here, assume the per day interest is 10, so for the next coming days in the month, it shows the result on a cumulative basis. However, at the start of each month, this value is reset and the cycle repeats for that month. My aim is to calculate the cumulative interest to date. I tried the following approach:

```sql
DECLARE @AI float = 0



CASE WHEN report_date<> Month_First_Date (***Calculated seperately***)
    THEN @AI + Interest
     ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @AI = @AI + Interest_lag (***previous date value:calculated separately***)
            SELECT @AI + Interest
        END 
    END AS Interest_Cummulative
```

Comment: FYI, storing monetary values in a floating point data type is always a bad idea. Use a precise data type. Otherwise you are very likely to end up will issues down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name='tblSample__')
DROP TABLE dbo.tblSample__
Go
 CREATE TABLE dbo.tblSample__(report_date DATETIME,interest DECIMAL(18,2))
 GO
 INSERT INTO dbo.tblSample__
SELECT  '2021/01/01 23:59:59', 1
UNION
SELECT  '2021/01/02 21:00:00', 5
UNION
SELECT  '2021/01/03 23:59:59', 1
UNION
SELECT  '2021/02/01', 6
UNION
SELECT  '2021/02/02', 10
UNION
SELECT  '2021/03/01', 12
GO
IF  NOT OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#T') IS Null
DROP TABLE #T
Go
SELECT *
,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, report_date), 0) AS StartOfMonth
,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, report_date) + 1, 0)LastOfNextMonth
INTO #T
FROM dbo.tblSample__ t
GO
SELECT * FROM #T
GO
SELECT * ,
    (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(interest,0)) 
    FROM #T tmp 
    WHERE 
        s.report_date >= tmp.StartOfMonth
        AND s.report_date < tmp.LastOfNextMonth 
        AND s.report_date >=tmp.report_date)
FROM dbo.tblSample__ s
```

OR

```
SELECT * ,
        (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(interest,0)) 
        FROM (
            SELECT *
                ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, report_date), 0) AS StartOfMonth
                ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, report_date) + 1, 0)LastOfNextMonth
            FROM dbo.tblSample__ t
            ) tmp 
    WHERE 
        s.report_date >= tmp.StartOfMonth
        AND s.report_date < tmp.LastOfNextMonth 
        AND s.report_date >=tmp.report_date)
FROM dbo.tblSample__ s
```

OR

```
SELECT * ,
        (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(interest,0)) 
        FROM (
            SELECT *
                ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, report_date), 0) AS StartOfMonth
                ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, report_date) + 1, 0)LastOfNextMonth
            FROM dbo.tblSample__ t
            WHERE  s.report_date >=t.report_date
            ) tmp 
    WHERE 
        s.report_date >= tmp.StartOfMonth
        AND s.report_date < tmp.LastOfNextMonth 
        )
FROM dbo.tblSample__ s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT report_date, 
       Interest,
       SUM(Interest) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(report_date), MONTH(report_date) ORDER BY report_date) Interest_Cummulative
FROM tablename
ORDER BY report_date
```